# Match objects with Start Date / End Date based on a range of Date

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, datetime

I have a list of jobs for a user, with different start dates and end dates.

The user has a project with also a start and a end date.

I want to know in what jobs the project matches as a range date

**Example :**

*Jobs:*

```
1.  [ 1.2.1999 ] - [ 3.4.2000 ]
2.  [ 4.4.2000 ] - [ 1.1.2004 ]
3.  [ 2.1.2004 ] - [ 6.8.2004 ]
4.  [ 7.8.2004 ] - [ 9.10.2005 ]
5.  [ 10.10.2010 ] - [ 12.12.2010 ]
6.  [ 1.1.2014 ] - [ 1.1.2016 ]
7   [ 2.1.2016 ] -  [ 10.10.2016 ]
```

*Project:*

```
[ 10.10.2004 ] - [ 10.10.2014 ]
```

*Result:*

Jobs: 4,5,6

**Code:**

```
Job {
    public DateTime StartDate{ get;set;}
    public DateTime EndDate {get;set;}
}

var jobs = new List<Job>();

// Will not work
jobs
.Where(e => e.StartDate <= project.StartDate &&
      e.EndDate >= project.EndDate)
.ToList();
```

Comment: Do you just want all `jobs` that are *entirely* inside the range of `project` or do you also want `jobs` that are *partially* inside the range of `project`? For example `jobA` is from `2000` to `2005`, `jobB` is from `2004` to `2006` and a `project` is from `2003` to `2007`. Do you only want `jobB` or both `jobA` *and* `jobB`?

Comment: With your logic now you would only get `jobs` that are "bigger" than the `project`, i.e. the `job` must start "before" (or equal to) the `project` **and also** end "after" (or equal to) the `project`.

Comment: @Corak partially and full. For Project with start / end : [ 10.10.2004 ] - [ 10.10.2014 ], I will match [ 7.8.2004 ] - [ 9.10.2005 ] , [ 10.10.2010 ] - [ 12.12.2010 ], [ 1.1.2014 ] - [ 1.1.2016 ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is kinda flawed, you're not actually checking whether the dates intersect, this will fix the issue and give you correct results:

```
jobs.Where(e => e.StartDate <= project.EndDate && e.EndDate >= project.StartDate).ToList();
```